# Django - Opening time formset

Tags: python, django, django-forms

### Context

I need to build a formset to allow opening hours to be set for a week.

### Status

Here is my model for opening times:

```
WEEKDAYS = [
  (1, _("Monday")),
  (2, _("Tuesday")),
  (3, _("Wednesday")),
  (4, _("Thursday")),
  (5, _("Friday")),
  (6, _("Saturday")),
  (7, _("Sunday")),
]

class OpeningHours(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey(User)
    weekday = models.IntegerField(choices=WEEKDAYS)
    from_hour = models.TimeField()
    to_hour = models.TimeField()
    class Meta:
        unique_together = (('user', 'weekday'),)
```

Here is how I generate a formset for a default week setting

```
UserOpeningHoursFormSet = formset_factory(UserOpeningHoursForm, extra=0)
hours = [{
        'weekday': day,
        'from_hour': '08:00',
        'to_hour': '18:00',
    } for day in range(1, 8)]
formset = UserOpeningHoursFormSet(initial=hours)
```

Here is how I get opening hours for the current user

```
user_hours = request.user.openinghours_set.all()
```

### Question

How can I put the user_hours into my formset ?

---

**Edit**

Example, let's say the user already has the hours for Monday and Thursday set in the db, the form should resemble:

```
weekday: Monday
from_hour: '09:00' # user_set
to_hour: '19:00' # user_set

weekday: Tuesday
from_hour: # default initial value
to_hour: # default initial value

weekday: Wednesday
from_hour: # default initial value
to_hour: # default initial value

weekday: Thursday
from_hour: '13:00' # user_set
to_hour: '15:00' # user_set

weekday: Friday
from_hour: # default initial value
to_hour: # default initial value

weekday: Saturday
from_hour: # default initial value
to_hour: # default initial value
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Expanding on @Rohan's answer:

I don't think modelformset is neccessary, just construct the **hours** like this

```
hours = [
    {'weekday': day, 'from_hour': '08:00', 'to_hour': '18:00'} 
    for day in range(1, 8) if not any(request.user.openinghours_set.filter(weekday=day))
    else
    {'weekday': day, 'from_hour': request.user.openinghours_set.filter(weekday=day).from_hour,
     'to_hour': request.user.openinghours_set.filter(weekday=day).to_hour}
]
```

Obviously, this is inefficient as it constructs one or three queryset(s) for each day, so rewriting it like this:

```
hours = []

openinghours_set = list(request.user.openinghours_set.all())
for day in range(1, 8):
    for openinghours in openinghours_set:
        if openinghours.weekday == day:
            hours.append({ fill from *openinghours* })
            break
    else:
        hours.append({ fill with default values })
```

Comment: Thank you, I'm interested by the `any()` (+1 for it) built-in function that I didn't know about. But I think your last example won't work because the days that don't follow numerically will be skipped.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [`modelformset`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/forms/modelforms/#model-formsets) and provide appropriate queryset.

```
formset = UserOpeningHoursModelFormSet(queryset=request.user.openinghours_set.filter())
```

There are also some other ways to change the queryset.

**EDIT:**

May be you can make use of `max_num` parameter while creating the formset instance along with `initial`. So you will get forms from existing instances and if instances are not enough, new forms will be created with data from initial dict.

```
    UserOpeningHoursFormSet = modelformset_factory(UserOpeningHoursForm, extra=7, max_num=7)
    formset = UserOpeningHoursModelFormSet(initial=hours,
                 queryset=request.user.openinghours_set.filter())
```

I haven't verified this, so I suspect it may add forms for each initial data items. So in worst case you need to create `hours` list with skipping for days for which hours are set.

Comment: How can I have my entire week initialized even if there is no value already set for the user ? I mean days initialized with default values if not set fot the user.

Comment: When you are creating new you can use `initial`. To update existing you can use queryset. Isn't that you are trying?

Comment: The goal is to be able to create or update the entire week whatever the existing values (see example in edited question)

Answer (score 0):

Here is what I ended up with:

```
user_hours = request.user.openinghours_set
hours = []
for day_id in range(0, 6):
    item = {'weekday': day_id, 'from_hour': '08:00', 'to_hour': '18:00'}
    if any(user_hours.filter(weekday=day_id)):
        my_item = user_hours.get(weekday=day_id)
        item['from_hour'] = my_item.from_hour.strftime('%H:%M')
        item['to_hour'] = my_item.to_hour.strftime('%H:%M')
    hours.append(item)
```

I would have preferred a more pythonic version...